# Chainable struct methods that satisfies multiple interfaces?

Tags: go, struct, go-interface

I have a need to create multiple structs with almost the same fields and methods with the same actions. Instead of doing that I thought, why not create a single struct and use interfaces to limit interactions. It worked great! Now the problem. I want the methods to be **chainable**. To do that, methods need to return a reference to the struct. After doing that, all the returns complain that `(struct) does not implement <interface> (wrong type for <method> method)`. Which is expected.

The question is, is it possible to use a single struct with multiple interfaces that has chainable methods? Or is creating individual, duplicate, structs for every interface the only way?

I thought of using composition but I still need to define methods that will call the embedded struct methods, in which case there's no difference to creating new pure structs.

Example problem:

https://play.golang.org/p/JrsHATdi2dr

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type A interface {
    SetA(string) A
    Done()
}

type B interface {
    SetB(string) B
    Done()
}

type t struct {
    a string
    b string
}

func (t *t) SetA(a string) *t { t.a = a; return t }
func (t *t) SetB(b string) *t { t.b = b; return t }
func (t *t) Done()            { fmt.Println(t.a, t.b) }

func NewTA() A {
    return &t{}
}

func NewTB() B {
    return &t{}
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")

    ta := NewTA()
    ta.SetA("a")
    ta.Done()

    tb := NewTB()
    tb.SetB("b")
    tb.Done()
}
```

Comment: Here is a good blog explaining why you should return structs and not interfaces: https://medium.com/@cep21/what-accept-interfaces-return-structs-means-in-go-2fe879e25ee8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `*t` as return type in `SetA` and `SetB` that means `t` are not implement A and B interface. The signature of `SetA` and `SetB` function of `*t` doesn't match with interface A and B accordingly.

Accually `SetA(a string) A` and `SetA(a string) *t` are not same think. You used `A` as return type for `SetA` in interface but use `*t` as return type for `t`, go doesn't support this. Same for `SetB` function

If you do like this then it will work because now function signature matched

```
func (t *t) SetA(a string) A { t.a = a; return A(t) }
func (t *t) SetB(b string) B { t.b = b; return B(t) }
```

Code in go playground [here](https://play.golang.org/p/EAq3Wd8nPSx)

Comment: What to do when methods overlap? for example `SetC`  that is part of `A` and `B` interfaces?

Comment: @CodeBreaker You have to match the interface function signature to implement them

Comment: So, you should implement two different function for both `SetC` if their signature are different